# Issues using [attribute!=value] and addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Its a fairly small script, but for some reasons im not able to get it working.
this is the function

```js
function stffsort(n) {
 $("[data-stff=" + n + "]").removeClass("hidden");
 $("[data-stff!=" + n + "]").addClass("hidden");
}
```

however, this piece here `$("[data-stff!=" + n + "]")` returns the whole page elements.

Comment: Can you show the HTML, and the JS you use to call this method.

Comment: HTML and JS seem to be irrelevant http://i.imgur.com/iNMvl1S.png?1 Same output on several pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however, this piece here $("[data-stff!=" + n + "]") returns the whole page elements.

Yes; it would return everything that doesn't have a `data-stff` set to that value, including things that don't have a `data-stff` attribute at all.

Try `[data-stff][data-stff!=" + n + "]"` and see if that gets you what you're after.

Comment: It worked. Thanks _All elements with a href attribute value not equal to "default.htm"_ this was basically fake

Answer (score 0):

This kind of selector requires the value to be in double-quote marks:

```
$('[data-stuff!="' + n + '"]')
```